# How do i load google fonts on the sever side node js

Tags: node.js, api, express, canvas, image-manipulation

I am using node js and canvas to create an API that writes text on a certain image. I successfully created a route such as -> /:sometext/:fontsize/:color/:position-x/:position-y and sends a static image with the text of the given font-size, color, and position on the canvas.

What I am unable to achieve is that I want to send the font family in the route and have that rendered on the screen. Plus, isn't there any other way that I can load at least google fonts without having to download the .ttf file.

What I have tried:

1. GetGoogleFonts npm package (which was a bad idea, since it was stuck at the installation)
2. WebFontLoader (Gives "Window is not defined" error)

### Steps to Reproduce

Currently, I am using a ttf file to load the font

```
router.get('/thumbnail/:name/:fontsize/:color/:posx/:posy', function (req, res, next) {
  let name = req.params.name;
  let fontsize = req.params.fontsize
  let positionx = req.params.posx 
  let positiony = req.params.posy
  let color = req.params.color

  let myimage = 'static/image1.jpg'

  const canvas = createCanvas(2000, 1000)
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  var str = "hi "+name
  registerFont('AvenirNext.ttf', { family: 'Avenir Next' })
  loadImage(myimage).then((image) => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0 , 0, 2000, 1000);
  ctx.font = fontsize + "px Avenir Next"
  ctx.fillStyle = color
  ctx.fillText(str, positionx, positiony);

  const out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/test.jpeg')
  const stream = canvas.createJPEGStream()
  stream.pipe(res)
  out.on('finish', () =>  console.log('The JPEG file was created.'))

})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to host the ttf files on your own server you could try to use the [Google Font Github repo](https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/).

```js
// missing imports
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
```

```js
const fontFamily = req.params.fontfamily; // example: ArchivoNarrow

// download font from github
const file = fs.createWriteStream(fontFamily + '.ttf');
const request = http.get('https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/' + fontFamily.toLowerCase() + '/' + fontFamily + '-Regular.ttf?raw=true', function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});

registerFont(fontFamily + '.ttf', { family: fontFamily });
```

```js
// delete font after the image is created
try {
  fs.unlinkSync(fontFamily + '.ttf');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Font I used for this example: [ArchivoNarrow](https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/archivonarrow/ArchivoNarrow-Regular.ttf)

Comment: Hi @Volk,
It seems like the registerFont method only takes in local files, because here is the error i get when i try your solution:
"no such file or directory, lstat '/home/kashaf/Development/imageManipulation-2/https:'"

Comment: @KashafShaikh I did not know that. I've changed the answer accordingly, if you still want to try.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs for `registerFont`](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#registerfont)

> To use a font file that is not installed as a system font, use registerFont() to register the font with Canvas. *This must be done before the Canvas is created.*

<sup>emphasis **not** mine</sup>

You are calling it **after** you created your canvas.

```
// first register the font
registerFont('AvenirNext.ttf', { family: 'Avenir Next' });
// then create the canvas
const canvas = createCanvas(2000, 1000);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var str = "hi " + name;
```

But note that this will try to load a font that would be available on your server. If you want to make it target a font on *://fonts.googleapis.com* server, you'd need to pass the full URI to the font file (not for the .css).

Also, you should wrap your family name inside quotes (`"`) since it contains a space:

```
ctx.font = fontsize + 'px "Avenir Next"';
```